# Can I choose NTFS when creating a USB bootable device?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

In step 5 of [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows?_ga=2.10469559.362657488.1531594066-1500063643.1531594066#6), it says to leave all other parameters on their defaults. Could it be a problem to select NTFS rather than FAT?

Comment: It will overwrite the existing FS anyway I guess.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/854749) answer it could be a problem since UEFI does not support NTFS.

Side note if possible it is suggested to use UEFI rather than legacy BIOS.

Comment: *"If you use flash drive with capacity exceeding 32GB you will only see 32GB if formatted with FAT32":* absolutely not true. I don't even begin to understand where you got this strange idea from.

Comment: yep, my bad, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Could it be a problem to select NTFS rather than FAT ?

A: It depends which tool you use, and your question links to a tutorial using Rufus in Windows, so my answer is focused on Rufus.

- If cloning, Rufus 'DD image mode', everything will be overwritten anyway with the content of the iso file, so it does not matter.
- If extraction, maybe. Some tools use the existing file system, some create a file system before extracting. I think Rufus 'ISO image mode' will create a file system (overwrite what was there before), and FAT32 will work in most computers.

Answer (score 0):

Have ever you tried [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) before. It's very easy to make bootable USB from an iso file.

Just a couple of clicks and you are done, without even thinking what is NTFS, FAT, UEFI, etc.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trtIM.gif) from the website.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [etcher.io](https://etcher.io/static/screenshot.gif))</sub>

Comment: For creating a bootable usb with windows 10 (april 2019 version) it warns me to use WoeUsb for Ubuntu.